# Extract any string after colon in Google sheet cell with multiple lines

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to extract everything after a colon : in a cell that has multiple lines within one cell.

Any text: John

Any text: Peter

Any text: Paul

Expected result

John

Peter

Paul

Any help, would be appreciated.

Tried

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,".*:(.*)")
```

But only returning first line

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VoKsbNZLldOFdS5-ybLLE0AxL5m6-UJh0M-M5ZD_Bq8/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: Sorry, should be accessible now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(BYROW(SPLIT(A:A,char(10)),LAMBDA(ax,JOIN(CHAR(10),REGEXEXTRACT(ax,":\s?(.*)$"))))))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
=INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(split(A1,CHAR(10)),".+: (.+)"))
```

Or, if you want it vertically, add TRANSPOSE:

```
=TRANSPOSE(INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(split(A1,CHAR(10)),".+: (.+)")))
```